# Click event on google charts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timeline, timeline.js

i have done something wrong and i can not figure it out what!
I am trying to make a function that on click to open a popup or a div in which i can display same more info about that particular product clicked.

Link to the site where you can see the example: http://trego.al/skai/schedule/

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Graphical Display - SKAI</title>

<!-- for mobile devices like android and iphone -->
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="graph/timeline.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="graph/timeline.css">

<style type="text/css">
        /* Styles for the page */
    html, body {
        font: 10pt arial;
    }

    #mytimeline {
    }

    #new {
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: 8px;

        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        /* Custom styles for the Timeline */
    div.timeline-frame {
        border-color: #5D99C3;

        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* For Firefox 3.6 and older */
    }
    div.timeline-axis {
        border-color: #5D99C3;
        background-color: #5D99C3;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5D99C3', endColorstr='#3A6DA0'); /* for IE */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#5D99C3), to(#3A6DA0)); /* for webkit browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #5D99C3,  #3A6DA0); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
    }
    div.timeline-axis-grid {
    }
    div.timeline-groups-axis {
        border-color: #5D99C3;
    }
    div.timeline-axis-text {
        color: white;
    }
    div.timeline-groups-text {
        color: #4D4D4D;
    }
    div.timeline-event {
        color: #000;
        max-height:50px;
    }
    div.timeline-event-content {
    font-size:12px;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeline = undefined;
    var data = undefined;

        function getSelectedRow() {
            var row = undefined;
            var sel = timeline.getSelection();
            if (sel.length) {
                if (sel[0].row != undefined) {
                    row = sel[0].row;
                }
            }
            return row;
        }


    google.load("visualization", "1");

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
        function drawVisualization() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'group');
            data.addColumn('string', 'content');
            data.addColumn('datetime', 'start');
            data.addColumn('datetime', 'end');
            data.addRows([

<?php
$host="******"; //replace with your hostname
$username="******"; //replace with your username
$password="******"; //replace with your password
$db_name="******"; //replace with your database
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "SELECT ac,flt,start,end FROM schedule"; //replace emp_info with your table name

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "['". $row['ac']. "','". $row['flt']. "',  new Date( ". $row['start']. " ),  new Date( ". $row['end']. " )], ";
}


?>              

            ]);

       // specify options
        var options = {
            width:  "100%",
            height: "99%",
            layout: "box",
            axisOnTop: true,
            eventMargin: 15,                    // minimal margin between events
            eventMarginAxis: 15,                 // minimal margin between events and the axis
            "min": new Date('2013-06-01'),        // lower limit of visible range
            "max": new Date('2013-06-30'),        // upper limit of visible range
            editable: false,
            showNavigation: true,
            OverlappingGridLines: true
        };

        // Instantiate our timeline object.
        timeline = new links.Timeline(document.getElementById('mytimeline'));

        // Draw our timeline with the created data and options
        timeline.draw(data, options);

        // Set a customized visible range
        var start = new Date(now.getTime() - 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        var end = new Date(now.getTime() + 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        timeline.setVisibleChartRange(start, end);

function onselect() {
  var sel = mytimeline.getSelection();
  if (sel.length) {
    if (sel[0].row != undefined) {
      var row = sel[0].row;
      document.title = "event " + row + " selected";
    }
  }
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(mytimeline, 'select', onselect);
// Or, when not using the Google API:
//   links.events.addListener(mytimeline, 'select', onselect);

    }


</script>

</head>

<body onresize="timeline.redraw();" style="background:#F9F8F6">

<div id="mytimeline"  style="background:#fff;min-width:900px;"></div>

<div id="info"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for example call Google hosted jquery :
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js

then try to use this function:

```
$( ".timeline-event" ).on( "click", function() {

alert($(this).children('div').text());


});
```

The above code will alert the product name of the clicked item.
Replace the alert with any action you need :)

Comment: still i am facing some difficulties, i paste the same code on the page but still not working. i' am not good at javascript, so if you can show me where to paste the script or an working example it will be perfect

Comment: have you included the jquery library? if not add this to your page header          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>